# WHERE clause needs an additional clause - I think

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

My **WHERE** clause below is suppose to get all status updates and check the user that posted them against a blocking table.

As long as the user is not being blocked by the user that's logged in, let the status be shown.

The **WHERE** clause is currently asking that the block should not be active if the status should be shown, which is correct.

The trouble is, at current, if any user has an active block on someone, the result will not be shown as active saying yes.

**Example:**

Take 3 users; 
**Tom, Bill** and **John**.

All status updates are being shown.
If **Tom** blocks **Bill**, **Tom** no longer can see **Bill** 's updates, and **Bill** cannot see **Tom**. - (That's how it should be too.)

But now because there is an active block on **Bill** by **Tom**, **John** cannot see his updates either.

My WHERE clause is not quite right is it?

```
//Get status results
        $sql = "SELECT 

        tbl_status.id as statID, 
        tbl_status.from_user as statFROM, 
        tbl_status.status as statSTATUS, 
        tbl_status.deleted as statDEL, 
        tbl_status.date as statDATE,

        tbl_users.id as usrID, 
        tbl_users.name as usrNAME,
        tbl_users.location as usrLOCATION,
        tbl_users.postcode as usrPOSTCODE,

        tbl_blocking.id as blockID,
        tbl_blocking.user as blockUSER,
        tbl_blocking.blocking as blockBLOCKING,
        tbl_blocking.date as blockDATE,
        tbl_blocking.active as blockACTIVE

        FROM tbl_status 

        INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id
        LEFT JOIN tbl_blocking ON tbl_users.id = tbl_blocking.user

        WHERE 
        tbl_status.deleted = '0'
        AND (tbl_blocking.user IS NULL
        OR (tbl_blocking.active = '0'
        AND tbl_blocking.user != :who
        AND tbl_blocking.blocking != :who))

        ORDER BY 
        tbl_status.date desc

        LIMIT 200

        ";
```

Comment: " WHERE tbl_blocking = 'x' " turns what was an OUTER JOIN into an INNER ONE. Move these conditions to the JOIN clause (the NULL one can stay where it is!). And read up on table aliases.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can you explain a little more. I'm a bit new to this. It's not the WHERE clause, it's the JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

By way of explanation...

```
 SELECT s.id        statID
      , s.from_user statFROM
      , s.status    statSTATUS
      , s.deleted   statDEL
      , s.date      statDATE

      , u.id        usrID
      , u.name      usrNAME
      , u.location  usrLOCATION
      , u.postcode  usrPOSTCODE

      , b.id        blockID
      , b.user      blockUSER
      , b.blocking  blockBLOCKING
      , b.date      blockDATE
      , b.active    blockACTIVE

   FROM tbl_status s

   JOIN tbl_users u
     ON u.id = s.from_user 

   LEFT 
   JOIN tbl_blocking b
     ON b.user = u.id
     OR (   b.active = 0      -- this might not be quite right!!!
        AND b.user != :who
        AND b.blocking != :who
        )

  WHERE s.deleted = 0
    AND b.user IS NULL

  ORDER 
     BY s.date DESC

  LIMIT 200
```

Comment: Thanks, but that just continues to do what ti did before

Comment: I don't understand why you have OR in there. Shouldn't that be AND?